# Converting Cubic curve to points

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx, geometry, javafx-8

I have multiple cubic curve that form shape I want  to convert this shape to a polygon without loosing the curvatures of the curves they. I have  a start point ,end point and two controls for each curve. Is there any algorithm or a way to convert this set of curves into polygon of multiple points?
Thanks in advance

```
private List<CubicCurve> curves = new ArrayList<>();
```

each red point represent the end of one curve and the start of the next
the two green dots between two red dots represent the the control points of the curve

[image]

Comment: Needs code.  I don't see how we give an answer that isn't a guess about what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Are you just asking for the [equation of a cubic Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves)?

Comment: if i understood the equation correctly then i think that what i want.
i just want to get corordinates of points along the curve from start to that end if i just have the four points

Comment: how to convert points to (X,Y) cordinates @James_D

Comment: Just use the equation I linked? Not sure what you are missing. The answer below shows how to get appropriately distributed values of the parameter t.

Comment: i don't know how to replace the p with (x,y)coordinates @James_D

Comment: P0, P1, P2, and P3 are the start, first control, second control, and end points, respectively.

Comment: i know but not sure how to input their values inside the equation@James_D

Comment: I'm confused. You must know those points to draw the cubic curves. So just plug their values into the equation, use varying values of t from 0 to 1, and for each value of t the equation gives you a point on the curve.

Comment: thank you very much @JAmes _D  i didn't understood it at first  but what i was mising that i can replac p with x when i want to get the x coords and y to get the y_cords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a much simpler and probably also more efficient solution to the above problem of finding the intermediate points of a Shape contour. It also uses the PathTransition but in a more straight forward way. I have only tested it with a Circle but I think this works with any Shape.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shape shape = new Circle(100);
    PathTransition pt = new PathTransition(Duration.ONE, shape, new Circle());
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    pt.playFromStart(); // force initialization
    pt.stop();
    for (double frac = 0.0; frac <= 1.0; frac += 0.05) {
        pt.interpolate(frac);
        System.out.println(pt.getNode().getTranslateX() + " " + pt.getNode().getTranslateY());
    }
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Evaluation took: " + (t1 - t0) + "ms");
}
```

Comment: +1, This solution is much better than mine. I was confused by recommendation of not using `interpolate` directly

Answer (score 1):

This process is called "curve flattening".

It suffices to compute intermediate points on the curve using the parametric equations, and recursively subdivide until the height of the triangle they form becomes neglectible.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answring but how can i compute them for cubic curve is there any equation to calculate them i found this equation https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/504c44ca5c5f1da2b6cb1702ad9d1afa27cc1ee0  that James_D mentioned but i don't know how to convert them to x,y coordinates

Comment: This is a functionality which is missing in JavaFX. If you were using an AWT Path, you would get that for free because the AWT Path provides a flattening path iterator.

Comment: @AhmedElshorbagy: this is already answered in the comments. Lookp Bézier curve.